# MySQL Field with custom values defined by user

Tags: mysql, sql

I know yo can do: SELECT "javier" as names;

```
#  names
  ----- 
1 javier
```

There is any way to get a custom field with user defined values for each row? something like SELECT ("javier","piter", "mike");
And obtain:

```
#  names
   -----
1  javier
2  piter
3  mike
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 'javier' as names
union all
select 'piter'
union all
select 'mike'
...
```

You can use `union all`.

If you need a column with auto rownumbers, you could do

```
select @rn := @rn+1 as `#`, names
from (
select 'javier' as names
union all
select 'piter'
union all
select 'mark') x,
(select @rn := 0) t
```